# docker swarm creation fails with "remaining connection slots are reserved..."

Tags: docker-swarm

Following the beginner's docs for OSX:

```
# Terminal started via Docker Quickstart Terminal app.
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox local
$ eval "$(docker-machine env local)"
$ docker run swarm create
```

Results in `pq: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`.

```
$ docker --version
# Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
$ docker run swarm --version
# swarm version 1.0.0 (087e245)

# Virtualbox version 5.0.10 r104061
# OSX 10.11.1 (15B42)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how the docs need to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swarm discovery service is down currently it seems.

See: http://status.docker.com/

Also: https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1503